# Being repeatedly ignored for a raise when close to retirement

Tags: salary

I have been with my employer for 18 years now. In the last 15 months, my work load has doubled, I have completed multiple projects as requested by management & am basically doing the same job as an "executive assistant" title without any compensation.

I've requested a raise on 5 separate occasions, all of which, I have been put on hold or ignored completely. My yearly reviews have all been outstanding, yet, my management team does not want to even discuss my request.

I can retire in 6 years so I don't want to leave my company. Where do I go from here?

Thank you

Comment: 5 requests in 18 years? Have you ever received a pay raise? If so, how long ago?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid). But your biggest leverage is the risk that you might leave. Since you indicate you are not willing to leave, what incentive does your employer have to give you a raise?

Comment: Ignoring a request for a raise is the same as saying "no".

Comment: If you switch companies, would you no longer be able to retire in 6 years?

Comment: If you retire from this company, will you get a pension?  Whereas, if you leave, you forgo that?  That is called 'golden handcuffs' - benefits that cost too much to lose, for a job that doesn't provide what you want.  If that is the case, I don't think this is a duplicate - being underpaid as you approach retirement is a special case, because the employer knows that leaving will have a much higher cost than for someone who is younger.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek is on the money, if they feel you're trapped they will likely ignore your requests for a raise.  Not a good position to be in at all.  Really need more info about retirement, are you in a position to change jobs and still retire? If so, would it be difficult to find another job? (PS I changed the title to reflect the scenario and better show this isnt a dupe question, hope you dont mind OP)

Comment: If they're the kind of company who's going to keep stringing you along for 6 years while increasing your workload without increasing your pay, how can you be sure that they're not the sort of company who'll do that for five years and then fire you in order to avoid the pension?  Do you have a union?  What country are you in?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have given more detail... I have been with this company for 18 years & I am grandfather into the "Rule of 80" retirement option (I have 6 years to go) to receive my pension. Every year I have gotten excellent reviews & the "across the board" 3% increase (which averages approx. $.59) but have never gotten a compensation increase due to the added workload & responsibilities.

Comment: The 5 times I have asked for a raise has been in the last 8 months. A year & half ago, my supervisor had me take numerous classes & online courses with the plan for me to take her position once she retired. When the time came, upper management never even looked at my resume, nor responded to either of our (my former manager & myself) requests. Since I have worked in the same department for 18 years, I would have liked to finish my career here as well. I have always LOVED my job...until a year ago. No union but I am in the medical field.

Comment: I guess my question is...Should I fight for the raise I deserve or just find another job internally & move on?

Answer (score 3):

I work for a pension/retirement organization - there are such different dynamics than for regular jobs around compensation.

Applying for internal positions is likely your best and only course of action - even just lateral moves. If you are offered another position inside the company, your new hiring manager may be able to negotiate a small raise for you when you move, even if it’s a lateral move.

They know they don’t have to pay you more to keep you, it is probably cheaper for them if you leave the company now, so it would be highly unlikely for them to give you a raise without a real reason.